# Aggregate and GROUP BY conflict with HAVING?

Tags: ms-access

I don't know if my logic in my query is incorrect, or if I simply have a syntax error, or both.

For each customer that had more than two orders, I want to list the customerID and the total number of orders placed.  However, this query is producing the following error, (in MS Access 2016)

> The level clause includes a reserved word that is misspelled or missing. or the punctuation is incorrect.

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(OrderID) AS OrderCount
FROM Order_T;
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING(COUNT(OrderID) > 2)
```

It produces no errors if I remove the HAVING clause, but then doesn't show only customers with more than 2 orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon after `FROM Order_T`. A semicolon is a statement delimiter, it should be at the end of the entire statement:

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(OrderID) AS OrderCount
FROM Order_T
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING(COUNT(OrderID) > 2);  <-- there
```

I am puzzled about how your query can run without errors if you just remove HAVING, but the semicolon is definitely out of place in the posted code.

Comment: I am also puzzled.  If i ever find out why, i will post it in here later

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% certain of the Access syntax but try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID, COUNT(OrderID) AS OrderCount
FROM Order_T
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING(COUNT(OrderID) > 2);
```

Comment: It Produces the same error.

Comment: Removed the semi colon in the middle of the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by removing distinct, it's redundant anyway:

```
SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(OrderID) AS OrderCount
FROM Order_T;
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(OrderID) > 2
```

I'm not sure what OrderCt is so I assumed it should read COUNT(OrderID)

Comment: Ok, I updated the code in original post above and ran it, but still same error.

Comment: The query is valid in SQL, so there might be a limitation in Access. Did you get an error code?

Comment: not in the message that Access gives me, however, when i click on the help button, it forwards me to the following page where the error code is displayed as 3136.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj681174%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Oh my gosh, you know what it was?  the semicolon on the second line.  I removed that and the error was gone.

Comment: Glad you found it. Add the ; to the question and add an answer that explains the problem. After 2(?) days you can accept your own answer